# WPML get permalink to the translated post from the original post

Tags: permalinks, plugin-wpml

I'm writing a plug-in to redirect visitors to the translated page if they have a German IP.

```
  add_action( 'wpml_loaded', 'geo_redirect_client' );
    function geo_redirect_client() {
        define( 'IP_LANG', 'de' ); // This will be coming from an some IP to country code API
        global $sitepress;
        if( ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE != IP_LANG ) {
            $languages = $sitepress->get_ls_languages();
            if( isset( $languages[IP_LANG] ) ) {
                $url = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
                $redirect_url = apply_filters( 'wpml_permalink', $url, IP_LANG );
                //wp_redirect( $redirect_url, 301 );
                //exit;
       echo $redirect_url;
            }
        }
    }
```

But the issue is wpml_permalink is not right.

Instead of getting www.mysite.com/de/kontakt/ it's getting www.mysite.com/de/contact/

Comment: This appears to be a [known bug in wpml](https://wpml.org/forums/topic/wpml_permalink-not-returning-correct-url/)(possible solution in the last reply).

Forcefully redirecting users at every pageload is a terrible idea. What if someone is currently in Germany (on a trip) but doesn't speak german? What if they simply prefer another language? Maybe redirect on first hit, but please allow visitors to switch languages afterwards!

Comment: @Iceable Thanks for the reply. It's per my client request. I understand that the IP redirection is not a very good idea and having some drawbacks. I will discuss with him about these issues later. However, the above issues can be solved by using `template_redirect` action hook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who is having a similar issue. You'll be able to solve the issue by using `wp`, `wp_head`, `wp_footer` or `template_redirect` action hooks.

In this case, `template_redirect` action hook solved my issue.

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_visitor' );
function redirect_visitor() {
    // Do your stuff
}
```